# can I use python to paste commands into LX terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi, tesseract, raspbian

okay, So for a school project I'm using raspberry pi to make a device that basically holds both the functions of an ocr and a tts. I heard that I need to use Google's tesseract through a terminal but I am not willing to rewrite the commands each time I want to use it. so i was wondering if i could either:

A: Use python to print commands into the LX Terminal
B: use a type of loop command on the LX terminal and save as a script?

It would also be extremely helpful if I could find out how to make my RPI go staight to my script rather than the raspbian desktop when it first boote up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use Python to execute it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do what you asked, but I think you lack some research of your own, as some of these answers are very "googlable".

You can print commands to LX terminal with python using "sys.stdout.write()"

For the boot question:

1 - sudo raspi-config

2 - change the Enable Boot to Desktop to Console

3 - there is more than one way to make your script auto-executable:

-you have the Crontab (which I think it will be the easiest, but probably not the best of the 3 ways)

-you can also make your own init.d script (best, not easiest)

-or you can use the rc.local

Also be carefull when placing an infinite loop script in auto-boot.

Make a quick google search and you will find everything you need.
Hope it helps.

D.Az